# Я правильно понимаю, что парсить сайты с помощью JS - невозможно?

Tags: javascript

Имеется ввиду именно обычный Js без фреймов, без **node.js** и других бек-энд фреймворков.
Ну и без предоставленного API.

Comment: Сложно будет, т.к. без node.js остается вариант поиска других интерпретаторов или делать через браузеры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отчасти это верно.

Одним из важных правил для JS, выполняющегося в браузере, является "скрипт может взаимодействовать по сети только с тем сервером, откуда он загружен"

Все другие обращения по сети будут ограничены - об этом позаботится браузер. И кажется, есть какие то исключения, связанные с CORS...

Но если Вы запускаете JS не в браузере, а в ноде - то весь интернет - ваш! В node.js нет ограничений на сетевое взаимодействие.